# Which syntax for sed command with backslah?

Tags: linux, sed, command-line

I need to change this kind of content :

```
"file":"\/home\/usr\/my-website.com\/data\/publication\/parameters\/21594\/1510849158.params"
```

into :

```
"file":"\/data\/publication\/parameters\/21594\/1510849158.params"
```

(I need to remove this string : `/home\/usr\/my-website.com\` )

But the Following command has no effect, i dont know why, and syntax is a little bit complicated :

```
sed -i 's#/home/usr/my-website.com#/#g'
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Are the backslashes part of the content? You would need to account for that in your `sed` expression, because currently it wouldn't recognize anything with extra backslashes in it.

Comment: I found an issue :'s/\\\/home\\\/usr\\\/my-website.com\\\/data//g'